# Save value from variable

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a problem, I cannot save a value into page.

My js:

```
var count = 0;

switch (index) {
case 0:
    count = count - 5;
    document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = (count);
    break;
case 1:
    count = count + 2;
    document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = (count);
    break;
case 2:
    count = count + 5;
    document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = (count);
    break;
}
```

My html:

```
<div id="point">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

How can i save the value?

Comment: What is the value of `index`? Also your `switch` statement is completely redundant as the same code is run in all cases.

Comment: Its working check fiddle=>http://jsfiddle.net/fj3fb/

Comment: In this fiddle,i set index =0; so It goes for case 0,sets value to 5 and Innerhtml shows value 5

Comment: Welcome to SO Jack_812  Don't just assume the code! Describe things you want to achieve giving a try is a good thing but make sure you're on the right way :)

Comment: Why is all the cases having same lines of code ?

Comment: why you tagged jquery?

Comment: Sorry,i would count the value from variable that increases or decrease from function's Switch

Comment: Removed jQuery tag, no jQuery needed at all :)

Comment: You can use jQuery if you want, but it's not needed. If you want plain javascript, check out my answer, if you want jQuery, you can check out the others :)

Comment: @Jack_812 Did you check out my solution? Please accept the answer which works for you. Otherwise, please let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: It the sam beetween jQuey and JavaScript,i want see the count out from switch,not into Switch.

Comment: What? You want the result after the switch? I did that. And all other answers are modifiable with the same logic as I used :)

Comment: I would like to count the sum of values​​ :),Not the only value of case's switch.

Answer (score 1):

It's running, see my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SE2Y9/)

```
var index = 0; // for demonstration, change that value

var count = 0;

switch (index) {
case 0:
    count = count - 5;
    $('#point p').text(count);
    break;
case 1:
    count = count + 2;
    $('#point p').text(count);
    break;
case 2:
    count = count + 5;
    $('#point p').text(count);
    break;
}
```

Note, the line `$('#point p').text(count);` is always the same in all cases, so you might want to put this after the switch-case.

Furthermore, I replaced your line: `document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = count;` by `$('#point p').text(count)`, to make use of jQuery. Hope it helps you getting started.

Answer (score 0):

You use `innerText`, which is not possible here. You can use `innerHTML` to make it work again.
A small [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cH5JL/) to show you one works, the other wont.

---

Also, you can simplefy your code a lot, and making it more flexible in the same effort:

```
var count = 0;
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        count -= 5;
    break;
    case 1:
        count += 2;
    break;
    case 2:
        count += 5;
    break;
}
// Only once, after the switch. If you want another target for the value,
// all you have to do is change this line, instead of every case.
document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
```

---

You do not need jQuery for this. Native JS often is faster.
If you do want to use jQuery, split the selector for optimal performance:

```
$('#point').find('p')
```